# Get "in_reply_to_status_id" from statuses/user_timeline Twitter in API PHP

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

Hey guys,
looked around but couldn't quite get an answer or figure it myself. Basically trying to get the "in_reply_to_status_id" value [statuses/user_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) and set it as variable in php ($replycheck), heres what I've written but to no avail

```
<?php
$consumerKey    = 'x';
$consumerSecret = 'x';
$oAuthToken     = 'x';
$oAuthSecret    = 'x';
// Create Twitter API objsect and fake a user agent to have higher rate limit
require_once("twitteroauth.php");
$oauth = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);
$oauth->useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9';

$reply_result = $oauth->get('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jwhelton');
$tweetid = $reply_result ->id;
$checkreply = $reply_result ->in_reply_to_status_id;
echo "<br /><br />Last tweet  was id'd as ".$tweetid." and was reply of ".$checkreply;
?>
```

Thanks to anyone who can give me a hand!

Comment: What if the status is not a reply to something else?

Comment: In the latest version of TwitterOAuth you should be constructing requests like this $reply_result = $oauth->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'jwhelton'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jwhelton on your browser to check.

Use: `in_reply_to_status_id_str` instead. The id number is too high for PHP to evaluate so it becomes `null`. So the code could be:

```
$reply_result = $oauth->get('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jwhelton');

foreach($reply_result as $i => $tweet) {
    $tweetid = $tweet->id_str;
    $checkreply = $tweet->in_reply_to_status_id_str;
    echo "<br /><br />Last tweet  was id'd as ".$tweetid." and was reply of ".$checkreply;
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me even when I confirmed last tweet was replying to another tweet :S

Comment: @dexcurl Use `$reply_result[0]->in_reply_to_status_id_str` to get the first result.